# Order of precedence of chained F.when conditions

Tags: pyspark

Suppose I have a chained F.when().otherwise condition:

F.when(Condition A, 1).when(Condition B, 2).otherwise(0)

and both Condition A and B are fulfilled, which takes precedence? Is there any way to `break` after a certain condition is fulfilled and not cascade into subsequent conditions?

Comment: the conditions are checked in the order in which the they are specified. so, A takes precedence in your example. i don't think it checks all conditions - only till it gets matched.

Comment: you could simply test that by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First encountered is the right one. In your case, it would be condition A, so output is 1